# Segmentation fault when ANDing enum

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a class CField and a class CBoard containing a 2d array of CField.

When I do this:

```
board(0,0)->Is (CField::CHECK)
```

I get a segfault in Is() method. GDB points me right after the &, so I think it's related to it. What's the cause?

Full code:
http://pastebin.com/vetShYsL - header
http://pastebin.com/pGNPpa8N - source

Comment: Provide more code. You're probably setting up your `board` incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 phase construction of a board is a bit annoying, and you have a bunch of extra code to manage it that you don't really need.

This is the bug though

```
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
            fields [x] = new CField [y];
```

index fields by i not x

```
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
            fields [i] = new CField [y];
```

Comment: i KNEW it that there is that kind of mistake somewhere! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The separate Create() method is useful for me, because I "create" multiple times the same instance of class (to return it to the beginning state).

Comment: Fair enough. I just prefer RAII if I can.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably nothing to do with the `&`.  The most likely reason is that `board(0,0)` is returning an invalid (or NULL) pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `operator()` is returning a null pointer when you call it on a freshly created `CBoard` object. Dereferencing a null pointer will result in undefined behavior, in your case a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your code actually creates the arrays needed for the `CBoard::fields`.  So when your `CField` code is called, `this` is an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 1):

There could be *many* possible problems going on here.  Since you didn't post the `Create` method of `CBoard` I don't know if you're ever properly allocating storage for `fields`.  Regardless, it's possible that `CField* operator() (int x_, int y_) const` may simply be returning null because the condition you wrote isn't evaluating to true.  Are you checking for a null pointer here?

Also, instead of getting involved in this crazy double-pointer memory management, why not just use an `std::vector`?

Comment: In this case, vector is overkill - I'm always creating and deleting whole table at once.

Comment: vector wouldn't be overkill. You spending this amount of time trying to rewrite what vector already does is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Your board is zero by zero. If you look at your logic, in `operator()`, you will try to return `fields[0][0]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: My board is 9x9. See edit 2. And my bound checking is correct, because I check for BAD, not GOOD values.